# (Android Firefox addon) need to read from Data.txt

Tags: android, firefox, firefox-addon

I am beginner on Android firefox addon. I have some difficulty to read a file.txt from path (/mnt/sdcard/) . I know it is possible for desktop but i don't know if that possible for android or not. I spend two days, but it doesn't work. Here is my code for bootstrap.js

```
 var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].  
             getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties)
             .get("/mnt/sdcard/", Components.interfaces.nsIFile);  
 file.append("NewDir");  
if( !file.exists() || !file.isDirectory() ) {   

file.create(Components.interfaces.nsIFile.DIRECTORY_TYPE, 0777);  
}  
this.log_file=file.path+"/Data.txt";

var is = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-input-stream;1"]
        .createInstance( Components.interfaces.nsIFileInputStream );
is.init( file,0x01, 00004, null);
var is = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-input-stream;1"]
        .createInstance( Components.interfaces.nsIFileInputStream );
is.init( file,0x01, 00004, null);

var sis = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/scriptableinputstream;1"]
        .createInstance( Components.interfaces.nsIScriptableInputStream );
sis.init( is );
var output = sis.read( sis.available() );
```

The code is not work

Comment: If you paste *just* what you provide in the question into a *bootstrap.js*, does it work on normal Firefox? and not Firefox for Android? Normally startup code would be located in a `startup()` function. This appears to not include this within a function. Is this actually how you have it in your (functional on desktop Firefox) code?

Comment: Thanks @Makyen , I put on startup() function for android but no thing showup.

Comment: Please provide a *instal.rdf* file (and a *chrome.manifest*, if used) so we don't have to create them to test this. Basically, it would be helpful to have a complete, but minimal, [mcve]: enough code such that we could just copy and paste it into a directory and test the add-on. If it's not what you are actually currently using, please try copy-&-pasting what's in the question into a new directory and verify that it both works on desktop Firefox, and does not work on Firefox for Android. Basically, unless someone has dealt with this specific issue, we're going to have to do some testing.